# PHP add number to starting number 9 times

Tags: php

Let's say have an item for sale for 20euro. For 2 items it costs 40euro, 3 items 60 euro. And you have maximum 8 items for sale.

How can you make these prices in PHP?

This is what I've tried:

```
$i=0;
$Price=20;
while($i < 9){
   $Price += $Price;
   $Prices[] = array( 'price' => $adultPrice,);
   $i++;
}
```

But this doesn't give me the output I desire, unfortunately.
So my goals is to get 20 40 60 80 100 120 140 160

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) With your loop condition now you have 9 iterations. 2) You probably want a `$total` variable starting at 0 and adding the price each iteration to it. Because right now you double the price every time.

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks! What you say makes sense, I'll try some stuff out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$i=1;
$Price=20;
while($i < 9){
   $newPrice = $Price * $i;
   $Prices[] = array( 'price' => $newPrice);
   $i++;
}   
echo "<pre>";
print_r($Prices);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 60
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [price] => 80
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [price] => 100
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [price] => 120
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [price] => 140
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [price] => 160
        )

)
```

**Live Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/560660)**

Comment: welcome.. glade to help you. :) Accept the answer is useful to other viewers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an array of arrays with prices use the following simple approach:

```
$i = 0;
$Price = 20;
$Prices = [];

while($i < 8){
    $Prices[] = array('price' => ++$i * $Price);
}

print_r($Prices);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 60
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [price] => 80
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [price] => 100
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [price] => 120
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [price] => 140
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [price] => 160
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$i = 1;
$Price = 20;
while($i < 9){
    $NewPrice = $i * $Price;
    $i++;

    echo $NewPrice."<br/>"; //store this where you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend! I see what my problem was now!

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Array_push() function for easily.